# Segmentation fault at clWaitForEvents

Tags: events, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm trying to understand OpenCL by constructing my own examples and playing around with them. So now I have simple kernel and two work items that should execute it but in a way that I can sum up the results of both work items. For that I used a barrier function:

```
kernel void parallel_operation(__global ulong *val) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    local unsigned int result[2] = { 0 };
    for (ulong k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        for (ulong j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            result[i] += (j * 3) % 5;
        }
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if (i == 0) {
        *val = result[0] + result[1];
    }
}
```

I also want to measure the time it takes for these work items to finish so I'm using events:

```
cl_event events;
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, &events);
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), val, 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clFlush(command_queue);
ret = clFinish(command_queue);
clWaitForEvents(1, &events);
```

When I run the code I get a segmentation fault at clWaitForEvents(1, &events). At first I thought it was because there are two work items, so there could be two events, but I couldn't find an example where this was the case. I also tried to do two clWaitForEvent calls but it didn't work.

So I suppose my question is, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` call looks suspect, especially `sizeof(cl_mem)`. Why that size? How is `val` defined, and how is the buffer created? I'd also check the return codes as @w-m suggests.

Comment: @pmdj There was a build failure, `local unsigned int result[2] = { 0 }` was an illegal assignment. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter to [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) is a single event, not a list of events.

<s>The specification allows it to be NULL in some cases:</s>

> If event is NULL, no event will be created for this kernel execution instance and therefore it will not be possible for the application to query or queue a wait for this particular kernel execution instance.

Maybe that's what's happening here.  I suggest you check your `ret` codes for earlier generic failures<s>, and then also check that `event` is not NULL before calling `clWaitForEvents`</s>.

Comment: This bit in the documentation is about the argument itself being a NULL pointer, not the returned event.

Comment: You are right! There was a build program failure, I shouldn't have initialized the local variable in the kernel like that. There is actually nothing wrong with the event, thank you!